# How to search a string in a file with exact length using python

Tags: python

I have file contains

```
google 
google talk browser
google talks
google talk
```

how to search "talks" in file using python and search exactly without extra string and print the line using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the comparison operator:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for index, line in enumerate(handle, 1):
        if line.strip() == 'google talk':
            print 'Match found on line', index
```

Comment: I wanted to search only "talk" and print the line and do not print "talk browser" and "talks" How can i do it.

Comment: I'm confused. Aren't you just searching for a line that is equal to `talk`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt = open("youfile.txt").read()
if re.search(r'[^\s]?google talk[\s$]?',txt):
    //code for string present
else:
    //code for string not-present
```